# Counting and listing all people in a certain row

Tags: php, mysql, count

Okay I'm trying to count the amount of people in a clan.  I have all the clans sent in a database like this: name(clan name) roomOwner(Owner of clan)
I have a user table like this: username, clan(Owner of Clan)
How could I get all of the people who have the same clan and count that?
I figure it would be something like this but I'm unsure atm

```
    function countMembers($clan) {
    include "mysql.ws";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT u.clan AS clan, a.*
FROM
  users u
  JOIN clans a ON(a.roomOwner = u.clan)
WHERE
 u.username = '$clan'");
    while($row = mysql_num_rows($query)){
        $members = count($row);
            return $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Here's the bigger comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Echo to the sentiments above, in case my +1s aren't enough.

Comment: @Truth copycat... :P but I have to admit - yours is indeed bigger...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select clan, count(username) as "# Of Members" 
from users 
where clan is not null
group by clan
```

Comment: How would I get rid of the row that has no clan?  It would say clan "" members 1340

Comment: If you join with clan to get all the other information about the clan, as in the original query, that should also filter out the null clans.

Comment: @Barmar you'll absolutely right, that's also a valid solution.

Comment: i'm kind of stuck now, I'm trying to print the number out, but it doesn't work right. http://pastebin.com/kPLaGjpd

Comment: run the query in the DB (using phpAdmin, for example) and make sure that it returns results, only then start debug you code.

Comment: It does work I tested it using sageofmali and it worked just fine. hmm

Comment: using a `return` statement inside a `while` loop will return only the first result.